# How to convert anything to string, in SML?

Tags: sml, polyml

I'm trying to implement a test function to compare and show error message if they are not equal:

```
exception AssertionErrorException of string

fun assert(testName, actual, expect) : bool =
    if actual = expect
    then true
    else raise (AssertionErrorException (testName ^ " failed. actual: " ^ actual 
                ^ ", expect: " ^ expect ));
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work if I invoke it with non-string parameters:

```
assert("test1", SOME [], NONE);
```

It can't be compiled, and the error message is:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: string * string * string
  operand:         string * 'Z list option * 'Y option
  in expression:
    assert ("test1",SOME nil,NONE)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Haskell, you would make your type an instance of the typeclass `Show` and implement an overloaded variant of the function `show :: Show a => a -> String` and then print `show x` rather than `x`. Unfortunately such a typeclass does not exist in Standard ML, and so you are forced to write your own non-overloaded variant of `show` for every datatype you want to pretty-print.

Some SML compilers (at least Moscow ML) support the overloaded function `makestring` that only works for a subset of built-in types and not any composite types. E.g. `makestring 2` and `makestring 2.0` both work, but `makestring (0,0)` does not. *(**Edit**: David Matthews points out in an answer below that `makestring` in PolyML is better.)*

If you wish to make a generic assertion function that pretty-prints the error, one thing you could do is create a datatype with a constructor for each type you wish to assert the value of. This would work like the "union" type in C.

```
exception AssertionError of string
datatype assert = AssertInt of int
                | AssertReal of real
                | AssertBoolBool of bool * bool
                | ...

fun assertPP (AssertInt i) = Int.toString i
  | assertPP (AssertReal r) = Real.toString r
  | assertPP (AssertBoolBool (b1,b2)) =
    String.concat ["(", Bool.toString b1, ", ", Bool.toString b2, ")" ]
  | assertPP (...) = ...

fun assert (testName, actual: assert, expect: assert) =
    actual = expect  (* ML infers equality for constructors *)
    orelse raise AssertionError (String.concat
        [ testName, " failed. actual: ", assertPP actual,
          ", expect: ", assertPP expect, "." ])
```

This is a poor man's replacement for overloading.

Answer (score 9):

*makestring* was present in some of the early drafts of Standard ML but was removed before the final version.  Poly/ML retained it as *PolyML.makestring* and this works on any type including structured types.

With this particular example it's possible to write

```
fun assert(testName, actual, expect) =
if actual = expect
   then true
   else raise AssertionErrorException(testName ^ " failed. actual: " ^
                PolyML.makestring actual ^ ", expect: " ^
                PolyML.makestring expect);
```

So

```
 assert("test1", SOME [], NONE);
```

prints

```
Exception-
AssertionErrorException "test1 failed. actual: SOME [], expect: NONE"
   raised
```

This happens to work because the type of *actual* and *expect* are equality types and this gives the compiler enough information to print the values properly.  In general, though, if *PolyML.makestring* is included in a polymorphic function all that will be printed is "?".  The solution is to pass in an extra parameter that is a function to convert the particular type to string.

```
fun assert(testName, actual, expect, toString) =
   if actual = expect
   then true
   else raise AssertionErrorException(testName ^ " failed. actual: " ^
                toString actual ^ ", expect: " ^ toString expect );
```

You then need to pass in a function that will convert the particular values into strings.  In Poly/ML this can be *PolyML.makestring*.

```
assert("test2", (1,2,3), (1,2,4), PolyML.makestring);
```

prints

```
Exception-
   AssertionErrorException
  "test2 failed. actual: (1, 2, 3), expect: (1, 2, 4)" raised
```

If you're using a different SML implementation you could still do the same and pass in your own conversion function for the particular type.

```
assert("test2", (1,2,3), (1,2,4),
     fn (a,b,c) =>
        String.concat["(", Int.toString a, ",", Int.toString b,
                      ",", Int.toString c, ")"]);
```

In effect you are implementing the type classes described in the previous answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
structure Printf =
   struct
      fun $ (_, f) = f (fn p => p ()) ignore
      fun fprintf out f = f (out, id)
      val printf = fn z => fprintf TextIO.stdOut z
      fun one ((out, f), make) g =
         g (out, fn r =>
            f (fn p =>
               make (fn s =>
                     r (fn () => (p (); TextIO.output (out, s))))))
      fun ` x s = one (x, fn f => f s)
      fun spec to x = one (x, fn f => f o to)
      val B = fn z => spec Bool.toString z
      val I = fn z => spec Int.toString z
      val R = fn z => spec Real.toString z
   end
```

Here’s an example use.

```
val () = printf `"Int="I`"  Bool="B`"  Real="R`"\n" $ 1 false 2.0
```

This prints the following.

```
Int=1  Bool=false  Real=2.0
```

for more information look [here](http://mlton.org/Printf)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to print out, just want to return a string that I can use in my error message

Comment: Maybe not an answer to the question but definitely very helpful. A tiny note: to make it compile you have to provide somewhere the identity function: "fun id x = x"